# MSDeploy "Hangs" on MSDeployPublish

Tags: iis-7, msdeploy

Trying to get MSDeploy working and it "hangs" on the MSDeployPublish task.
It says

> "Start Web Deploy Publish the Application/package to
>   `https://myserver:8172/msdeloy.axd?site=mysite` ... Starting Web
>   deployment task from source: archiveDir(path to archive) to
>   Destination: auto()."

And it just stops. It will sit like this for 30 minutes, or more I suppose, before I kill the process.

On the server it is deploying to, in this case myserver, there is an error from MSDeploy that reads:

> ERROR_SERIALIZER_ALREADY_DISPOSED - An error occurred on a callback
>   thread. These errors are usually benign and are handled automatically.
>   The details are below:  System.Web.HttpException: The remote host
>   closed the connection. The error code is 0x800704CD.    at
>   System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.RaiseCommunicationError(Int32
>   result, Boolean throwOnDisconnect)    at
>   System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.ExplicitFlush()    at
>   System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush(Boolean finalFlush)    at
>   System.IO.BufferedStream.FlushWrite()    at
>   System.IO.BufferedStream.Flush()    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextWriter.Flush()    at
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.TraceEventStreamSerializer.WriteKeepAliveEvent()

No other error logs or messages that I can find. 
I can hit the url to msdeploy, for example if I go to `https://myserver:8172/msdeloy.axd` in a browser I get the self signed certificate warning and then get prompted for credentials, so it appears MSDeploy on the server is up and running.

The server (myserver) is Windows 2008R2 with IIS7.

What really sucks, is if I REBOOT the server that I am deploying to (myserver) IT WORKS!

Any ideas on what is going on here?

Comment: What version of MSDeploy is installed on the server? client?

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing, although in my case this is a much more prevalent error message: ERROR_SERIALIZER_ALREADY_DISPOSED - An error occurred on a callback thread. These errors are usually benign and are handled automatically. The details are below: 
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream.
   at System.IO.BufferedStream.Write(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush(Boolean flushStream, Boolean flushEncoder)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextWriter.Flush()
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.TraceEventStreamSerializer.WriteKeepAliveEvent()

Comment: @JoeYoung, you say that it works - how long does it continue to work before it breaks again? I've found that it will hang four or five times in a row but if I persist it will eventually go through...

Comment: @TerenceLewis, at this point I don't really know. I just got it hooked up with our build server for a project we are starting, but does not have a lot going on in it yet. I have had it work for a couple days with a couple "test" deploys then it hangs.

Comment: I get the same error message as Terence in my Microsoft Web Deploy error log.  I cannot restart my production web server (as it is the only one hosting my site and I have no control over this...corporate environment).  My alternative/workaround was to restart Web Management Service (I had to start again after the Restart failed with a weird message about a directory not being able to be deleted).  I am not sure what caused the original problem, but I am continuing to monitor it.

Comment: Having the same issue unfortunately :-(

Comment: Me too.. Did anyone find a solution to this problem? It is driving me crazy! It works on other servers, but just one keeps giving this problem...

Comment: Same issue here with MSDeploy 3 client. Restarted "Web Management Service" to get it running again.

Comment: Same issue. We're using v2. Thankfully, prod never does this, test rarely does this, dev does this *all the time*. It seems to have started when we switched from HyperV to VMware. Anyone else on VMware?

Answer (score 4):

Just went through the same thing. This is the response from my hosting company that resolved the issue.

"While investigating, we found that the connection attempt was hanging on our end. The Web Management Service needed to be stopped to edit settings for the management service but upon attempting to stop this service, it would not shut down so we force killed the process and after starting it back up (no changes were made to settings), Visual Studio is making connections with Web Deploy without issue."